# Sepolia Smart Contract - Withdrawal function

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethers.js, typescript, sepolia

I've deployed a simple wallet solidity smart contract on the sepolia test network, and trying to test withdrawals. The first two attempts succeeded but I run into an 'insufficient funds' error despite having >0.5 ETH in both my test address and contract address.

Contract address: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x660d92eC6BCb5CC3db989aA05D46b046c6069EFB

Creator address:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x717ed4454b2e13d5be7ce629957a89982065182d

simplewallet.sol

```
interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract SimpleWallet {
    event Deposit(address indexed sender, uint amount);
    event Withdrawal(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount);

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    receive() external payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function withdrawETH(address payable _to, uint256 _amount) external {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        _to.transfer(_amount);
        emit Withdrawal(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
}

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

App.tsx (frontend):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import SimpleWalletABI from './SimpleWalletABI.json';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import CoinFlipPage from './CoinFlipPage'; // Import your new CoinFlipPage component
import HomePage from './Homepage';

import './App.css';

const contractAddress = "0x660d92eC6BCb5CC3db989aA05D46b046c6069EFB";


function App() {
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState(String);
  const [depositAmount, setDepositAmount] = useState('');
  const [walletBalance, setWalletBalance] = useState('');
  const [withdrawalAmount, setWithdrawalAmount] = useState('');
  const [recipientAddress, setRecipientAddress] = useState('');
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  // Check if the wallet is connected when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    checkIfWalletIsConnected();
  }, []);

  // Check for wallet connection
  const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async () => {
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      if (!ethereum) {
        console.log("Make sure you have MetaMask installed!");
        return;
      }

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
      if (accounts.length !== 0) {
        const account = accounts[0];
        setCurrentAccount(account);
        if (account) {
          await getWalletBalance(account);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("No authorized account found");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  // Connect to MetaMask wallet
  const connectWalletHandler = async () => {
    const { ethereum } = window;
    if (!ethereum) {
      alert("Please install MetaMask!");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      if (accounts.length > 0) {
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
        if (accounts[0]) {
          await getWalletBalance(accounts[0]);
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("No authorized accounts found");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  // Create a function to get the wallet balance
  const getWalletBalance = async (account: string) => {
    if (!window.ethereum) return;
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, SimpleWalletABI.abi, provider);
    
    try {
      const balance = await provider.getBalance(contractAddress);
      setWalletBalance(ethers.formatEther(balance));
      console.log("Account: " + account);
      console.log("Balance: " + balance);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  // Handle deposit
  const handleDeposit = async () => {
    if (!depositAmount || !window.ethereum) return;
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    try {
      const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
        to: contractAddress, // Send to the contract address
        value: ethers.parseEther(depositAmount)
      });
      await tx.wait();
      alert(`Deposited ${depositAmount} ETH`); // Notify user of successful deposit
      console.log(`Deposited ${depositAmount} ETH`);
      getWalletBalance(currentAccount + `${depositAmount}`); // Update wallet balance
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleWithdraw = async () => {
    if (!withdrawalAmount || !recipientAddress || !window.ethereum) return;
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, SimpleWalletABI.abi, signer);
  
    try {
      const tx = await contract.withdrawETH(recipientAddress,
        ethers.parseEther(withdrawalAmount)
      );
      await tx.wait();
      alert(`Withdrawn ${withdrawalAmount} ETH to ${recipientAddress}`);
      console.log(`Withdrew ${depositAmount} ETH`);
      // Optionally, update the balance
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setCurrentAccount('');
  }

  // Function to toggle dark mode
  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode) {
      document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    }
  }, [darkMode]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={
          <HomePage
            currentAccount={currentAccount}
            connectWalletHandler={connectWalletHandler}
            depositAmount={depositAmount}
            setDepositAmount={setDepositAmount}
            handleDeposit={handleDeposit}
            walletBalance={walletBalance}
            withdrawalAmount={withdrawalAmount}
            setWithdrawalAmount={setWithdrawalAmount}
            recipientAddress={recipientAddress}
            setRecipientAddress={setRecipientAddress}
            handleWithdraw={handleWithdraw}
            logout={logout}
            darkMode={darkMode}
            toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
            getWalletBalance={() => getWalletBalance(currentAccount)} // Passing getWalletBalance as a prop
          />
        } />
        <Route path="/coinflip" element={<CoinFlipPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
  
  export default App;
```

error from browser console (withdraw ETH):

```
App.tsx:124 Error: Error: execution reverted: "Insufficient balance" (action="estimateGas", data="0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014496e73756666696369656e742062616c616e6365000000000000000000000000", reason="Insufficient balance", transaction={ "data": "0x4782f779000000000000000000000000717ed4454b2e13d5be7ce629957a89982065182d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c68000", "from": "0x717ED4454b2E13d5BE7CE629957A89982065182d", "to": "0x660d92eC6BCb5CC3db989aA05D46b046c6069EFB" }, invocation=null, revert={ "args": [ "Insufficient balance" ], "name": "Error", "signature": "Error(string)" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.10.0)
    at makeError (ethers.js?v=5cbfd590:324:15)
    at getBuiltinCallException (ethers.js?v=5cbfd590:11887:10)
    at _AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (ethers.js?v=5cbfd590:11958:12)
    at BrowserProvider.getRpcError (ethers.js?v=5cbfd590:18991:26)
    at BrowserProvider.getRpcError (ethers.js?v=5cbfd590:21233:18)
    at ethers.js?v=5cbfd590:19179:27
```

As long as I have a `tranfer` method in my contract, I will be able to withdraw from the contract balance right? I am not sure why this error is getting thrown and would love some advice on how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

As, you're storing the records of addresses and their respective deposited amounts in `balances` mapping variable. And while withdrawing, you've put this condition:

```
require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
```

Which is ensuring that the address (`msg.sender`) who is withdrawing the amount from the contract, must have deposited at least the same amount into the contract. As, whatever amount is being deposited by any address is being incremented in the corresponding `balances` record via this line of code in the `receive()` function:

```
balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
```

So, your transaction is being reverted with **Insufficient balance** error while withdrawing any amount using your wallet `0x717ED4454b2E13d5BE7CE629957A89982065182d`, because you haven't deposited any amount into the contract from the same wallet.

You can also confirm the same by checking the `balances` value corresponding to that address, it says `0`. Or if you're connected using the same wallet, then you can also check the `getBalance()` function, as it retrieves the `balances` value corresponding to `msg.sender` (i.e., the address who is calling the function).

[image]

So, once you deposit some amount (say **x Sepolia-ETH**) into the contract from a particular wallet (say `0x717ED4454b2E13d5BE7CE629957A89982065182d`), then you'll be able to withdraw any amount (i.e., **<=x Sepolia-ETH**) from the contract to any payable address using the same wallet (i.e., `0x717ED4454b2E13d5BE7CE629957A89982065182d`).